# full width cover not showing in mobile device

Tags: html, css

I want to show full width and specified height image in my page that is working properly with desktop but in mobile it is not   showing full width image.

My code is

```css
.cover {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
<img class="default_cover_image" id="cover-img" style="background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/62272/pexels-photo-62272.jpeg');">
</div>
```

how to fix this problem and make working it for all devices?

Comment: I'm added an answer below,don't forget to tick it if it's useful :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this , i dont know why you set background image to img tag ,
The `<img>` tag defines an image in an HTML page. `<img>` tag has two required attributes: src and alt.

you can simply call `<img src="" alt=""/>` and if you want to set background image you need to set `background-size:cover`

```css
.cover {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    float:left;
}
.cover img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/62272/pexels-photo-62272.jpeg" alt="img"/>
</div>
```

and other way using

```css
.cover {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    float:left;
 background:url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/62272/pexels-photo-62272.jpeg');
 background-size:cover;
}
.cover img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
```

Comment: hi did you check the answers i gave you ? accept the answer if it is use full to you

Comment: Thank you both answers are great

Answer (score 3):

add

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

to your style sheets,it's works fine.I'm added the snippet below.

```css
.cover {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/62272/pexels-photo-62272.jpeg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
```

Comment: @xrcwrn choose the best,she added my answer also to her post because probably she also thinks that is good.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.cover {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
    <img class="default_cover_image" id="cover-img" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/62272/pexels-photo-62272.jpeg" style="height:100%; width:100%;">
</div>
```